# AJAX request onchange not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, heroku

I am trying to create an AJAX request after a file is uploading using the Filestack API on Heroku. I can't seem to figure out the Javascript for the onchange event. This is what I have, could you please show me what I am doing wrong? Nothing is firing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//api.filestackapi.com/filestack.js"></script>
      <input type="filepicker" data-fp-apikey="AJQAmlHqT46EYTTyhk0upz" data-fp-extension=".csv"
       onchange="function() {
    var mydata = event.fpfile.url //current video time
    $.ajax({
       url : "/url/to/save/file_url",
       type:"POST",
       data:mydata,
       success:function(msg){}
          })
    };">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be greatly improved. And it will avoid common errors such as the wrong usage of double quotes you've made.

You can first create a function that will take care of your ajax call.

```
function saveFile(){

    // Check that the function is called
    alert('savefile() called');

    var mydata = event.fpfile.url;
    $.ajax({
       url : "/url/to/save/file_url",
       type:"POST",
       data:mydata,
       success:function(msg){}
    });
}
```

End then in your event you call this function.

```
onchange="saveFile()"
```

**Update:**

Your question was most based on how to use the event onchange to call an ajax request. Which I explained above.

But now, you should obviously take a look to filestack javascript API documentation:
https://www.filestack.com/docs/file-ingestion/javascript-api/pick

Lot of examples are available.

Comment: This isn't triggering the function to run

Comment: I've updated the code. Please try and let us know if you see the content of the alert. As well do you have any error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed it

```
<script>
  function onUpload(event) {
  var name = event.fpfile.url;
  jQuery.ajax({
   data: { name },
   type: 'post',
   url: "/purchase_orders/import_open_order"
  });
 }
</script>
```